# Simplifying boolean expressions

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, simplify, boolean-operations

I am having trouble simplifying these two boolean expressions and was hoping for a solution. I have put my work so far under each one.

```
 1)~B(A + A * B)
 My work:
 ~BA + ~BAB
 ~BA + 0
 ~BA
 I wasn't sure if you could distribute ~B into A*B to equal ~BAB like that

 2)~B + ~(A*B) + ~C
 Totally lost on this one. 
 My thinking:
 ~B + (~A + ~B) + ~C (demorgans)
 1 + ~A + ~C
 1 + ~C
 1
```

Are these correct or am I on the right path? Thanks

Comment: Write out the truth tables to see if you have it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you distributed the ~B and simplified properly.
2. No.  Good use of DeMorgan's Theorem, but you lost ~B after that.  ~B + ~B
   simplifies not to 1 but to ~B.

   ~B + (~A + ~B) + ~C

   ~B + ~A + ~C

   ~A + ~B + ~C

   Or, if you want to apply DeMorgan's Theorem again:

   ~(ABC)